# How to get specific error message to Data Validation using Regex with python 3

Tags: regex, python-3.x, validation, if-statement

**How do i get a specific output like the below examples:**

> **example 1** - If the user inputs ***Alberta, UN***. I want to be able to see the print result as ***I'm sorry, UN is an invalid province abbreviation.***
>   I would love if the program can display an exact error in relation to user's input. Instead of an error saying ***I'm sorry this is an error***, without any specific message to let the user know where his/her fault is.

I would really appreciate it if i could get some results, because i have been brainstorming on how to make it work

```
# Import
import re

# Program interface
print("====== POSTAL CODE CHECKER PROGRAM ====== ")
print("""
Select from below city/Province and enter it
--------------------------------------------
Alberta, AB,
British Columbia, BC
Manitoba, MB
New Brunswick, NB
Newfoundland, NL
Northwest Territories, NT
Nova Scotia, NS
Nunavut, NU
Ontario, ON
Prince Edward Island, PE
Quebec, QC
Saskatchewan, SK
Yukon, YT
""")

# User input 1
province_input = input("Please enter the city/province: ")

pattern = re.compile(r'[ABMNOPQSYabcdefhiklmnorstuvw]| [CBTSE]| [Idasln], [ABMNOPQSY]+[BCLTSUNEK]')

if pattern.match(province_input):
    print("You have successfully inputted {} the right province.".format(province_input))
elif not pattern.match(province_input):
    print("I'm sorry, {} is an invalid province abbreviation".format(province_input))
else:
    print("I'm sorry, your city or province is incorrectly formatted.")
```

Comment: You've used a comma in your example, but a dash in your code. Which of them is correct? Also - it's not clear what you're trying to match with the regex

Comment: It's a comma. I want the user's input to be Alberta, AB. Although that's not the point. The point is if i were input Alberta, RB. It should state that RB is an invalid province abbreviation, Although Alberta is correct.

Comment: So you only want to compare the last two letters to the list of valid states?

Comment: Compare how? what I am saying is, i need a way to modify my code, so if a user inputs Alberiros, AB. It states Alberiros is not a valid city/province and if user inputs Alberta, RB. It states RB is an invalid province abbreviation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to generalize your question, so it will check if the first part of the input is a valid city and the second is a valid state abbreviation, when "valid" means each of them appears in its relevant valid inputs list.

The core of the code is the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/5RvPNJ/1) `([A-Z][A-Za-z ]+), ([A-Z]{2})`, which matches two groups: the first group contains the city - and after a comma and a space - the second group contains the state abbreviation (which must consist two capital letters).

Please notice there are 5 possible outputs, according to the validity of each part.

```
import re

cities = ["Alberta", "British Columbia", "Manitoba"]
states = ["AB", "BC", "MB"]

province_input = input("Please enter the city/province: ")
regexp = r"([A-Z][A-Za-z ]+), ([A-Z]{2})"

if re.compile(regexp).match(province_input):
    m = re.search(regexp, province_input)
    city_input = m.group(1)
    state_input = m.group(2)
    if city_input not in cities and state_input not in states:
        print("Both '%s' and '%s' are valid" % (city_input, state_input))
    elif city_input in cities:
        if state_input in states:
            print("Your input '%s, %s' was valid" % (city_input, state_input))
        else:
            print("'%s' is an invalid province abbreviation" % state_input)
    else:
        print("The city '%s' is invalid" % city_input)
else:
    print("Wrong input format")
```

I tried to make the code as clear as possible, but please do let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Thanks, you really helped.

Comment: @EmpressObazee take another look at the beginning of the code. The lists of valid inputs are (very) partial. I only gave you 80% of the way, and didn't do the manual part of adding ALL the valid values

Comment: @ GalAbra i saw it earlier i can always complete it. Thanks once again. I am an average atm in python i would love a way to reach you through mail or skype perhaps, in relation to python no other reasons if unsure of my request.

Answer (score 0):

Not a Python programmer but I think if you `import regex`
the new regex lib replacement, it will give you access to the
*Branch Reset* construct.

Using that, it's trivial to divide City and Province into 3 groups.

So, just match with this regex
`[ \t]*(?|(Alberta)(?:[ \t]*,[ \t]*(?:(AB)|(\w+)))?|(British[ \t]+Columbia)(?:[ \t]*,[ \t]*(?:(BC)|(\w+)))?|(Manitoba)(?:[ \t]*,[ \t]*(?:(MB)|(\w+)))?|(New[ \t]+Brunswick)(?:[ \t]*,[ \t]*(?:(NB)|(\w+)))?|(Newfoundland)(?:[ \t]*,[ \t]*(?:(NL)|(\w+)))?|(Northwest[ \t]+Territories)(?:[ \t]*,[ \t]*(?:(NT)|(\w+)))?|(Nova[ \t]+Scotia)(?:[ \t]*,[ \t]*(?:(NS)|(\w+)))?|(Nunavut)(?:[ \t]*,[ \t]*(?:(NU)|(\w+)))?|(Ontario)(?:[ \t]*,[ \t]*(?:(ON)|(\w+)))?|(Prince[ \t]+Edward[ \t]+Island)(?:[ \t]*,[ \t]*(?:(PE)|(\w+)))?|(Quebec)(?:[ \t]*,[ \t]*(?:(QC)|(\w+)))?|(Saskatchewan)(?:[ \t]*,[ \t]*(?:(SK)|(\w+)))?|(Yukon)(?:[ \t]*,[ \t]*(?:(YT)|(\w+)))?|()(\w+)())`

Check the groups in this order :

if *NO* match :  `Please enter 'City, Province' from the list`
else if length $1 equals 0 : `'$2' is not a valid City`
else if length $3 > 0 : `'$3' is not a valid Province`
else if length $2 equals 0 : `Please enter a Province`
else : `Thank you, your entry is valid '$1, $2'`

Demo:  https://regex101.com/r/MrlqEN/1

Expanded

```
 [ \t]*     
 (?|
      ( Alberta )                   # (1)
      (?:
           [ \t]* , [ \t]* 
           (?:
                ( AB )                        # (2)
             |  ( \w+ )                       # (3)
           )
      )?
   |  ( British [ \t]+ Columbia )   # (1)
      (?:
           [ \t]* , [ \t]* 
           (?:
                ( BC )                        # (2)
             |  ( \w+ )                       # (3)
           )
      )?
   |  ( Manitoba )                  # (1)
      (?:
           [ \t]* , [ \t]* 
           (?:
                ( MB )                        # (2)
             |  ( \w+ )                       # (3)
           )
      )?
   |  ( New [ \t]+ Brunswick )      # (1)
      (?:
           [ \t]* , [ \t]* 
           (?:
                ( NB )                        # (2)
             |  ( \w+ )                       # (3)
           )
      )?
   |  ( Newfoundland )              # (1)
      (?:
           [ \t]* , [ \t]* 
           (?:
                ( NL )                        # (2)
             |  ( \w+ )                       # (3)
           )
      )?
   |  ( Northwest [ \t]+ Territories )  # (1)
      (?:
           [ \t]* , [ \t]* 
           (?:
                ( NT )                        # (2)
             |  ( \w+ )                       # (3)
           )
      )?
   |  ( Nova [ \t]+ Scotia )        # (1)
      (?:
           [ \t]* , [ \t]* 
           (?:
                ( NS )                        # (2)
             |  ( \w+ )                       # (3)
           )
      )?
   |  ( Nunavut )                   # (1)
      (?:
           [ \t]* , [ \t]* 
           (?:
                ( NU )                        # (2)
             |  ( \w+ )                       # (3)
           )
      )?
   |  ( Ontario )                   # (1)
      (?:
           [ \t]* , [ \t]* 
           (?:
                ( ON )                        # (2)
             |  ( \w+ )                       # (3)
           )
      )?
   |  ( Prince [ \t]+ Edward [ \t]+ Island )  # (1)
      (?:
           [ \t]* , [ \t]* 
           (?:
                ( PE )                        # (2)
             |  ( \w+ )                       # (3)
           )
      )?
   |  ( Quebec )                    # (1)
      (?:
           [ \t]* , [ \t]* 
           (?:
                ( QC )                        # (2)
             |  ( \w+ )                       # (3)
           )
      )?
   |  ( Saskatchewan )              # (1)
      (?:
           [ \t]* , [ \t]* 
           (?:
                ( SK )                        # (2)
             |  ( \w+ )                       # (3)
           )
      )?
   |  ( Yukon )                     # (1)
      (?:
           [ \t]* , [ \t]* 
           (?:
                ( YT )                        # (2)
             |  ( \w+ )                       # (3)
           )
      )?
   |  ( )                           # (1)
      ( \w+ )                       # (2)
      ( )                           # (3)
 )
```